# how to bind two different vertex buffer to two slots

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

how to bind two vertex buffers into different slots (slot0 and slot1),

I want something like this in OpenGL(QT):

```
QGLBuffer VB0, VB1;

VB0.bind(0);
VB1.bind(1);
```

I have this so far:

```
verticesBuffer = new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);
verticesBuffer->create();
verticesBuffer->bind();
verticesBuffer->setUsagePattern(QGLBuffer::DynamicDraw);
verticesBuffer->allocate(vertices.constData(), _ANGLE_CNT * _RANGE_CNT * 6 * sizeof(QVector3D));
verticesBuffer->release();

colorsBuffer = new QGLBuffer(QGLBuffer::VertexBuffer);
colorsBuffer->create();
colorsBuffer->bind();
colorsBuffer->setUsagePattern(QGLBuffer::DynamicDraw);
colorsBuffer->allocate(_ANGLE_CNT * _RANGE_CNT * 6 * sizeof(float));
colorsBuffer->release();
```

Could you write a sample to explain what I should do to bind both these buffers to slots?

Comment: Huh? What is a *"slot"* at all? What is it you are actually trying to do? Do you want to source different vertex attributes from different buffers? Or do you want  to bind different buffers to different transform feedback streams? Or what else?

Comment: I want to source different vertex attributes from different buffers.
i ask the questions with my directx view.

Comment: @user159626 Then you should rather check how OpenGL actually works, since it is much more involved than binding the buffer to an attribute *"slot"*.

Comment: I don't know anything more. how should I do it?

Comment: Hard to explain if there isn't any OpenGL background, as this would require an extremely broad answer. See [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification) for a start and then look for the corresponding Qt functions doing that.

Comment: see code above please. (tnx for the link)

Comment: "*Could you write a sample to explain what I should do to bind both these buffers to slots?*" No. Stack Overflow is not a "write some code for me" service. There are dozens of resources that explain the basic workings of using buffer objects from vertex data. The [OpenGL Wiki has an article](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification) that goes into explicit detail about how this stuff works in OpenGL.

Comment: Are you referring to? : http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml

Answer (score 0):

It's not like when people do not understand my question exactly, they feel free to give negative votes to it. I asked the same question in another forum and I got the exact answer. My account has been blocked by this stupid way of voting. So, here I answer my own question:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO_ID);
glBindVertexArray(VAO_ID);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer_0_id);
 glVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
...


glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,buffer_1_id);
 glVertexAttribPointer(POSITION_1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), 0);
...

layout(location = POSITION_0) in  vec3  Position0;
layout(location = POSITION_1) in  vec3  Position1;
```

Comment: As you know, 'slot' is Direct3D specific name. I had same wonder about GL side, but cannot figure out what should I call it in GL style. If you showed some DX API, maybe they understood about it.

Answer (score -1):

update:
added this to the initialization part:

```
verticesSize = sizeof(vertices);
colorsSize   = sizeof(colors);

glGenBuffers(2, vbods);                       

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbods[VERTEX]); 

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
             sizeof(vertices)+sizeof(colors),
             vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), sizeof(colors), colors);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

and this to the render part:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbods[VERTEX]);
glVertexPointer(2, QVector3D, 0, 0);   
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (GLvoid *) (ANGLE_COUNT * RANGE_COUNT * 6));
```

Comment: That's only half the work and not even the part where you actually specify the buffer data as source for an attribute. And by all means don't use those `...ARB` functions, VBOs are core since about 15 years. Really, get an actual OpenGL learning resource (or look at the links *again*, since they tell you much more and this is most probably *not* what you gained from the links in the comments, whatever those links were where you got that from, they are certainly *not* "useful").

Comment: And in the end that (the VBO management) is what `QGLBuffer` already does for you, the more interresting part is that about attribute locations and vertex format specification.